# Big Cartel: Is there any way to retrieve the order date in the confirmation email?

Tags: bigcartel

In the confirmation email, I would like to get access to the date the order was placed.

Since order object does not appear in the [object documentation](http://help.bigcartel.com/developers/themes/#variables-1), I am not sure which fields actually exist. All other elements I needed appeared in the default email, but there is no reference to the order date.

On the other hand, in Dugway, I tried to use the date filter. Liquid documentation [here](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers#advanced-output-filters) suggests you can use it as follow:

```
Hello {{ 'now' | date: "%Y %h" }
```

But this will not get through in Dugway: what appears on the page is 'now'.

Is there any way to get access to the order date ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables for email confirmations aren't currently documented anywhere, sorry about that -- however you can use the `{{ order.date }}` variable in your confirmation email.

And Shopify's version of Liquid varies slightly, instead of using 'now' you can use 'Today' - `{{ 'Today' | date: "%Y %h" }}` will work.