# How do you get the current time from bigcartel's server?

Tags: javascript, date, time, liquid, bigcartel

Is there a way to get the current date and time from bigcartel's server, either with Liquid or JavaScript? I'm building some custom functionality in my store that needs to have a consistent (not client-side) time source. I would only need to access it once per page load.

Here's what I've tried so far, based on [another date-related bigcartel question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212199/big-cartel-is-there-any-way-to-retrieve-the-order-date-in-the-confirmation-emai):

```
var currentDate = new Date({{ 'Today' | date: "%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M" }});
currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() - 1);
```

This does retrieve today's date, but it doesn't consistently update as I refresh the page. Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: Liquid will get a fresh date/time after each time I edit/save and reload a particular page, or if a certain amount of time has elapsed after the first page load (I haven't done enough testing to pin down exactly how much time... maybe 2 or 3 hours... or more?).

Also, the stuck date/time is unique to each product page. For example, if I load Product Page A at 9:30, and Product Page B at 9:32, they'll both be stuck on those respective times. Both pages are being rendered from the same code.

I've never worked with Liquid before, but I assume it should retrieve fresh data from the server with each page load, similar to PHP. Am I mistaken about that?

EDIT 2: It gets even weirder. Sometimes I have a query string appended to the end of the URL of a given product page (e.g. `?comicID=225`). But if I change the number in the query string (or even just type in random garbage instead) it will retrieve a new stuck date. So it appears any unique URL gets a unique stuck date from whenever it first gets loaded!

Comment: Using Liquid does the date update at all after the first view? I thought Liquid gets compiled into static content so it wouldn't re-evaluate each time you refresh the page.

Comment: I added more info in response to your question.

Comment: Okay, my thoughts at this point are that Liquid scripts are only getting re-evaluated every few hours or the content being served is cached by your browser. Are there cache headers being specified in the HTTP response that contains the bigcartel date?

Comment: @ErikGillespie, I'm not sure of the answer to your question, but your suggestion to look into the HTTP response headers did steer me in a helpful direction, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ended up making an `XMLHttpRequest()` with JavaScript to get the current time from the HTTP response headers, and it seems to be working perfectly for my purposes. Here's my working code:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
var currentDate = new Date(req.getResponseHeader('date'));
```